# Problems with make responsive map areas in vue 3

Tags: html, image, vue.js, dictionary, vuejs3

I have an existing image map with click event on areas in a vue 3 project. Images scale according to browser size, but the image coordinates are obviously fixed pixel sizes. What options do I have to resize the image map coordinates? im new to vue 3, grateful for any help and ideas

i try this in simple component but its not work, the click event is not on the areas

```
<script>

export default {
  props: ['selfValue'],
  data() {
    return {
      current: '',


    };
  },
  methods: {

    press(key) {
      this.current = `${this.current}${key}`;

      console.log(key)
    },

  },
  watch: {
    current() {
      this.$emit('pressed', this.current);
    },
    selfValue() {
      this.value = this.selfValue;
    },
  },

};
</script>

<template>

  <div class="passwordkeyboard">
    <img class="keypadimg"
      src="/pwd.png" usemap="#image-map" />
      <map id="image-map" name="image-map">
    <area @click="press(1)" alt="key1" coords="57,15,9,64" shape="rect">
    <area @click="press(2)" alt="key2" coords="76,16,125,64" shape="rect">
    <area @click="press(8)" alt="key8" coords="144,16,191,64" shape="rect">
    <area @click="press(3)" alt="key3" coords="211,15,260,64" shape="rect">
    <area @click="press(4)" alt="key4" coords="278,15,327,64" shape="rect">
    <area @click="press(7)" alt="key7" coords="9,95,58,144" shape="rect">
    <area @click="press(5)" alt="key5" coords="76,95,125,144" shape="rect">
    <area @click="press(6)" alt="key6" coords="143,95,192,144" shape="rect">
    <area @click="press(0)" alt="key0" coords="211,95,260,144" shape="rect">
    <area @click="press(9)" alt="key9" coords="277,95,328,144" shape="rect">
</map>
 
</template>

<style>

</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recalculate the coords one resize event of the image and pass it into components using template; first create array with coords sorted on keys 0 to the 9

```
const coords = [
  [222, 95, 260, 44]
  ...
]

<area v-for="(coords, index) in recalculatedCords" @click="press(index)" alt="`key${index}`" :coords="coords.join(',')" shape="rect">
```

Better yet, save percent values in the arrays (calculate percents in respect to the original image size). Then just iterate over coords array each time the image resizes, multiplying each coordinate with a new image with/height.

Comment: i tried the method you suggested and its work like charm, thank you very much, i appreciate your help

Comment: sorry i forget to accept